# How to pass token/credentials from one MVC Web app to Another MVC Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am trying to figure out how to pass a user’s login token/credentials/claims form one app to another. I am hosting both apps on the azure cloud and for costing purposes I want to try and keep as much of a customer’s resources on their subscription as possible as the traffic to and from the website has a cost attached to it id like to keep their silo there. But I want to have a single login portal for all clients that then sends them to their individual locations based on there user info. That part I have figured out the part I can’t get is how to pass an authorization token after they log in on the main portal to there web app. I control all the apps and databases but none of the research I have done has showed me how to pass this token. I believe this is possible as I know that you can pass tokens to api’s. I would greatly appreciate any insight and help.

Comment: Research SSO (Single Sign On) in .net.

Comment: Maybe you can share authentication cookies between your apps. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.